# Proof of holonomic constraints for a wheel on a track

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, constrained-dynamics

[image: Wheel rolling without slipping on a track]

I'm faceing a problem of a thin wheel of radius R rolling without slipping on a track (y = f(x); on xy-plan). The wheel plane stays vertical and tangent to the track at the contact point P. $\alpha$ is the angle to the y-axis and stays tangential to the track.

Intuitionally I would say the rolling wheel on the track has only one degree of freedom. But I'm failing to prove that. And I hope you can give me some hints, to prove it.

I like to reduce the generalized coordinates $ \vec{q} = [x_C;y_C;z_C;\alpha;\phi;\theta]$ with holonomic constraints.

-Wheel stays vertical: => $\theta = 0$ (1.) scleronmic constraint
-Wheel stays on xy-plane:    => $ z_C-R = 0$ (2.) scleronmic constraint

Then i have $ \vec{q} = [x_C;y_C;\alpha;\phi;]$.

-Rolling without slipping: $ \vec{v_P} = \vec{v_C} + \omega \times \vec{r_{CP}}=0 $ 
=> $\dot{x_C}+ R\dot{\phi}sin(\alpha) = 0 $ (3.) nonholonomic constraint
=> $\dot{y_C}+ R\dot{\phi}cos(\alpha) =0 $ (4.) nonholonomic constraint

-Rolling on track: => $ y_C = f(x_C)$ (5.) 
-$\alpha$ tangential to track: => $\frac{dx}{dy} = tan(\alpha)$ (6.)

I'm sure that combinations of the equation (3.),(4.),(5.) and (6.) will lead to integrable constraints so that they will become holonomic but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Rolling without slipping constraint is $s=R\phi$.

Comment: I used this constraint already at the contact point from the wheel to the plan, where the velocity has to be zero. Or do you see an opportunity to combine s with the function f(x)

Comment: Everything is determined by arc length $s$ from O to P. $v=R\dot\phi$ is just the time-derivative of $s=R\phi$. The position of P along the curve $f(x,y)$ is uniquely determined by arc length $s$ from the origin. The rotation angle $\phi$ of the disk is determined by $s=R\phi$ and the co-ordinates of C are $(x,y,R)$ where $(x,y)$ are the co-ordinates of P.